# How to replace a single column values in R

Tags: r, variables

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
   A  B  C   D
1. 5  4  4   4
2. 5  4  4   4
3. 5  4  4   4
4. 5  4  4   4
5. 5  4  4   4
6. 5  4  4   4
7. 5  4  4   4
```

I'd like to add a "zero" to all variables in column C. For example, like this:

```
   A  B  C   D
1. 5  4  40  4
2. 5  4  40  4
3. 5  4  40  4
4. 5  4  40  4
5. 5  4  40  4
6. 5  4  40  4
7. 5  4  40  4
```

How do I do this?

Comment: As your questions get more and more complicated, you might start thinking of producing a reproducible example. See how to make one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4):

Just multiply column C by 10. Assuming your `data.frame` is called `myData`:

```
myData$C <- myData$C*10
```

Comment: @Rnewbie, if (and only if) the answers meet your needs, do be sure to mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really like constantly having to refer to `myData$A` to refer to the `A` column. A nice alternative expression is to use `within`:

```
myData = within(myData, {
   C = C * 10
   D = D + 4
   E = C + D
 })
```

especially when more column manipulations need to be done in the same `data.frame` I like this syntax better. Or even better:

```
myData = transform(myData, C = C * 10, D = D + 4, E = C + D)
```

or use `mutate` from the `plyr` package. This has the advantage over `transform` that it works iteratively, allowing you to use newly created columns:

```
# fails
myData = transform(myData, C = C * 10, new_col = C + 4, even_newer = new * 3) 
#works  
myData = mutate(myData, C = C * 10, new_col = C + 4, even_newer = new * 3)
```

Comment: `within` is definitely useful.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is numeric, mrdwab's suggestion is the best:

> myData$C <- myData$C*10

This style works for the "data.frame". So if you keep your data in a matrix you should use:

> myData[,3] = myData[,3] * 10

Finally if your data is NOT NUMERIC (character), you can act as below:

> myData$C = paste(myData$C, "0", sep="")